# Creating an Oscillator Node in Scala.js using js.Dynamic

Tags: javascript, scala, web-audio-api, scala.js

I'm using the online version of Scala-js-fiddle. So far, I've been able to successfully declare an Audio Context:

```
val ctx = js.Dynamic.newInstance(js.Dynamic.global.AudioContext)()
```

Now, I want to create an oscillator node. I tried (unsuccessfully):

```
val oscillator = ctx.js.Dynamic.global.createOscillator()
```

When I saved this, the Scala-js-fiddle said compilation was successful. However, I also had error messages. The main one was:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'Dynamic' of undefined
```

How can I properly create an oscillator node and set the value of its frequency using js.Dynamic?

In regular Javascript, I would simply write something like this:

```
var oscillator = ctx.createOscillator();
oscillator.frequency.value = 400;
```

Would I have to use js.Global.Function(...)? How would that work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved! As it turns out, after creating an AudioContext like this

```
val ctx = js.Dynamic.newInstance(js.Dynamic.global.AudioContext)()
```

you can call the JavaScript methods normally:

```
val o = ctx.createOscillator()
```

Comment: A little gist on the internals: `ctx` is of type `js.Dynamic` which extends `scala.Dynamic`. That means the Scala compiler allows **any** method to be called and has it return another `js.Dynamic`. That's why in your question you could call `js` on `ctx` and then `Dynamic` on it's result, etc.